# How to split 10 rows in 2 columns in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[image]

10 rows in mysql table, i need to split 10 rows to 5 rows in one column and another 5 in another column.

[image]

What will be the query to get such result?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code (php in this instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below query it will dynamically break rows into column without any parameter, just replace "Time" by your column name.

```
      SELECT b.*, c.* from 
      (SELECT CEILING(COUNT(id) / 2) as totalId from test) as a JOIN 
      (SELECT id as id1, Time as column1 FROM test) as b LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT id as id2, Time as column2 FROM test) as c
      ON b.id1 = c.id2-a.totalId 
      WHERE b.id1 < a.totalId+1
```

You can replace * by column name also like this:

```
      SELECT b.column1, c.column2 from 
      (SELECT CEILING(COUNT(id) / 2) as totalId from test) as a JOIN 
      (SELECT id as id1, Time as column1 FROM test) as b LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT id as id2, Time as column2 FROM test) as c
      ON b.id1 = c.id2-a.totalId 
      WHERE b.id1 < a.totalId+1
```

Comment: This works well for an even number of rows, but leaves out the last value if there are an odd number https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ddc26266abeb26ab1b3e79f830a578c1

Comment: Corrected version for odd number of rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1f29d5171662865af351d2e3844fae3d, which will like here, will fail with `auto_increment`  column gaps. So like suggested, please use application code for this.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite horrible to do in MySQL and you are better of doing it in an application language.

Crudely you could do the following however it lacks any sort of scalability:

```
SELECT a.value, b.value
FROM tbl a
JOIN tbl b ON a.id=b.id-5
WHERE a.id < 6
```